# How to enable File Transfer in a Multithreaded Chat using Sockets in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to build a simple chat server with Sockets in Java (no gui) using multithreading. I managed to get the simple message sent between users and it works fine. However, I'm now trying to send a file from one user to the other but I can't seem to get the logic right.

So far, I have created a `/send` command (e.g `/send /user/folder/file.jpg`) and I get the location. Now, I'm not sure how to go about sending those files to the other user. I am trying to make a copy of the file to the Server Folder, and then prompt the other user that a file was received. The other user decides whether or not to accept the file. I'm totally lost here and not sure how to proceed. I made 3 different folders, one for user1, one for user2 and one for Server. So user1 sends a file from his folder to Server(which holds a copy) and then prompts user2 to accept the file. If user2 accepts the file, the file is sent to users2 folder. I'm totally lost about the way to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current code:

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


/*The Chat Server*/
public class Server {
    //Initializing sockets
    private static ServerSocket socket_server = null;
    private static Socket socket_client = null;

  //We accept 3 connections from 3 different users at once
  private static final int number_of_users = 3;
  private static final clientThread[] num_threads = new clientThread[number_of_users];

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int port = 1337;
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.out.println("Server started...\n"
          + "Using port number " + port);
    } else {
      port = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
    }

    //Opening the server socket on port number 1337 (<port_number> > 1023)
    try {
      socket_server = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    /*
     * Create a client socket for each connection and pass it to a new client
     * thread.
     */
    while (true) {
      try {
        socket_client = socket_server.accept();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++) {
          if (num_threads[i] == null) {
            (num_threads[i] = new clientThread(socket_client, num_threads)).start();
            break;
          }
        }
        if (i == number_of_users) {
          PrintStream os = new PrintStream(socket_client.getOutputStream());
          os.println("Chat server is full.:'( Try to come back later.^^");
          os.close();
          socket_client.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Client Thread.
 */
class clientThread extends Thread {

  private String clientName = null;
  private DataInputStream is = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket socket_client = null;
  private final clientThread[] num_threads;
  private int number_of_users;

  public clientThread(Socket socket_client, clientThread[] num_threads) {
    this.socket_client = socket_client;
    this.num_threads = num_threads;
    number_of_users = num_threads.length;
  }

  public void run() {
    int number_of_users = this.number_of_users;
    clientThread[] num_threads = this.num_threads;

    try {
      /*
       * Create input and output streams for this client.
       */
      is = new DataInputStream(socket_client.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(socket_client.getOutputStream());
      String name;
      while (true) {
        os.println("Enter your student number:");
        name = is.readLine().trim();
        if (name.indexOf('@') == -1) {
          break;
        } else {
          os.println("The name should not contain '@' character.");
        }
      }

      /* Welcome the new the client. */
      os.println("Welcome " + name
          + " to the 1337 Chat Room.\nTo leave enter /quit in a new line.");
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++) {
          if (num_threads[i] != null && num_threads[i] == this) {
            clientName = "@" + name;
            break;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++) {
          if (num_threads[i] != null && num_threads[i] != this) {
            num_threads[i].os.println("*** User " + name
                + " has entered the chat room...Don't troll please... ***");
          }
        }
      }
      /* Start the conversation. */
      while (true) {
        String line = is.readLine();
        if(line.startsWith("/send")){
          String[] fileLocation = line.split(" ");
          if(fileLocation.length > 1 && fileLocation[1] != null){
            synchronized(this){
              for(int users = 0; users < number_of_users; users++){
                if (num_threads[users] != null && num_threads[users].clientName != null) {
                  num_threads[users].os.println("<" + name + "> has sent the file " + fileLocation[1]);
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (line.startsWith("/quit")) {
          break;
        }
        /* If the message is private sent it to the given client. */
        if (line.startsWith("@")) {
          String[] words = line.split("\\s", 2);
          if (words.length > 1 && words[1] != null) {
            words[1] = words[1].trim();
            if (!words[1].isEmpty()) {
              synchronized (this) {
                for (int i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++) {
                  if (num_threads[i] != null && num_threads[i] != this
                      && num_threads[i].clientName != null
                      && num_threads[i].clientName.equals(words[0])) {
                    num_threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    /*
                     * Echo this message to let the client know the private
                     * message was sent.
                     */
                    this.os.println(">" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          /* The message is public, broadcast it to all other clients. */
          synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++) {
              if (num_threads[i] != null && num_threads[i].clientName != null) {
                num_threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + line);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++) {
          if (num_threads[i] != null && num_threads[i] != this
              && num_threads[i].clientName != null) {
            num_threads[i].os.println("*** The user " + name
                + " is leaving the chat room !!! ***");
          }
        }
      }
      os.println("*** Bye " + name + " ***");

      /*
       * Clean up. Set the current thread variable to null so that a new client
       * could be accepted by the server.
       */
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++) {
          if (num_threads[i] == this) {
            num_threads[i] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      /*
       * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
       */
      is.close();
      os.close();
      socket_client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client implements Runnable {

  // The client socket
  private static Socket socket_client = null;
  // The output stream
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  // The input stream
  private static DataInputStream is = null;

  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // The default port.
    int port = 1337;
    // The default host.
    String host = "localhost";

    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.out
          .println("Welcome to the 1337 Chat Room...\n"
                  + "Using port number " + port);
    } else {
      host = args[0];
      port = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
    }

    /*
     * Open a socket on a given host and port. Open input and output streams.
     */
    try {
      socket_client = new Socket(host, port);
      inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      os = new PrintStream(socket_client.getOutputStream());
      is = new DataInputStream(socket_client.getInputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
          + host);
    }

    /*
     * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data to the
     * socket we have opened a connection to on the port port.
     */
    if (socket_client != null && os != null && is != null) {
      try {

        /* Create a thread to read from the server. */
        new Thread(new Client()).start();
        while (!closed) {
          os.println(inputLine.readLine().trim());
        }
        /*
         * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
         */
        os.close();
        is.close();
        socket_client.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
    }
  }

  /*
   * Create a thread to read from the server. (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
   */
  public void run() {
    /*
     * Keep on reading from the socket till we receive "Bye" from the
     * server. Once we received that then we want to break.
     */
    String responseLine;
    try {
      while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(responseLine);
        if (responseLine.indexOf("*** Bye") != -1)
          break;
      }
      closed = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code to ask someone to go through.

Comment: @OldProgrammer See the part where I have an if statement with the command `/send`. Basically I am trying to send a file from this block of code. I've read around a lot. Can't seem to get it right